# How to make Safari always start with a blank page on iOS 17.3.1?

Tags: iphone, ios, safari

The Safari start page can be customised to show Favourites, frequently visited sites, recently closed tabs, etc. But how can Safari be set to start with a blank page? This is on iOS 17.3.1.

Comment: Can't you just Edit the options and turn everything off?